# Rails routing to multiple route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I'm using devise for rails.
I have the following route for devise.

> devise_for :user

Which routes to 'user/sign_in' and several other.

So I want to change this route to: get 'login'. Is this possible?
I tried doing

> match 'login', to: 'user/sign_in', via: :get

Which did not work as well, what am I doing wrong, and what does the above code do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `/login` for `sign_in` add the following to your `config/routes.rb`:

```
devise_scope :user do 
    get 'login', to: 'devise/sessions#new'
end
```

Comment: It worked for me but cannot seem to understand how these things work.

Comment: Devise has lots of good resource here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki.  For those that are outside, we all will have to read their source and sometimes ask them questions directly.

Answer (score 0):

This'll work:

```
devise_for :user, :path => 'login'
```

You might need `:users` and not `:user`, FYI.